# ASP .NET Core MVC upload text files to an existing db with logged in user foreign key

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Now I'm working on my Cloud Storage Project and the main idea of it is to use authorization system provided by Identity Framework and let users upload and download files to an existing table (AspNetFiles - created by me). Moreover, it's important to save all uploaded files to folder in project directory (~/wwwroot/Files/). Now I'm on the way to build upload files system, so:

1. I made new table AspNetFiles in the direction of other AspNet... tables provided by Identity and Upload-Database NuGet func after creating Migration;
2. Created new "WorkSpaceController" in "~/Controllers/" for managing files (upload, sort in grid and download) for every logged in user;
3. Created functions for FileManager view (this is the page for displaying upload, grid and delete files experience) + some other functions for saving files in wwwroot, getting logged in user "Id" and etc.

My dbo.AspNetFiles has the next columns:

- FileID (PK, int, not null) with identity (1,1) parameter
- FileName (varchar(60), not null)
- FileData (varbinary(max), not null) - for store uploaded file data in table
- FileExtension (varchar(15), not null)
- FileDate (varchar(20), not null)
- Id (FK, nvarchar(450), not null) as the primary key of logged in user from dbo.AspNetUsers

After debugging application I get some errors:

- **InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.** System.Convert.ChangeType(object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
- **InvalidCastException: Failed to convert parameter value from a FormFile to a Byte[].** Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.CoerceValue(object value, MetaType destinationType, out bool coercedToDataFeed, out bool typeChanged, bool allowStreaming)
  So yeah I know that I use a IFormFile type for "FileData: from "FileDataModel" but it's for saving file locally in project folder as I mentioned previously (~/wwwroot/Files/).

I'm a new user in ASP.NET Core, so I tried many ways from YouTube and articles of how to save files locally and in table of SQL database, but I didn't find any way to do it both and save files with existing Identity Framework with connection to logged in user by foreing key "Id" in table for upload files and download to pc.

Hope u can help me with it. Don't gudge too much :D

This is the code:

**FileDataModel** (in ~/Models/)

```
namespace TextCloud.Models
{
public class FileDataModel
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public IFormFile FileData { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public string FileDate { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
}
```

**WorkSpaceController** (in ~/Controllers/)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using TextCloud.Models;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using TextCloud.Areas.Identity.Data;
namespace TextCloud.Controllers
{
public class WorkSpaceController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
    private readonly UserManager<TextCloudUser> _userManager;

    public WorkSpaceController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, UserManager<TextCloudUser> userManager)
    {
        this.webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot GetConnection()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appSettings.json").Build();
        return builder;
    }

    public IActionResult FileManager()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FileManager(FileDataModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string uniqueFileName = null;
            if (model.FileData != null)
            {
                DateTime FileDate = DateTime.Now;
                model.FileDate = FileDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                model.Id = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
                string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Storage");
                uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.FileData.FileName;
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                model.FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(model.FileName);
                model.FileName = model.FileData.FileName;
                if (model.FileDate != null)
                {
                    string connctn = "Server=DESKTOP-LRLFA5K\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TextCloud;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connctn);
                    con.Open();
                    string commnd = "insert into AspNetFiles(FileName, FileData, FileExtension, FileDate, Id) values (@FileName, @FileData, @FileExtension, @FileDate, @Id)";
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(commnd, con);
                    com.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.FileName;
                    com.Parameters.Add("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = model.FileData;
                    com.Parameters.Add("@FileExtension", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.FileExtension;
                    com.Parameters.Add("@FileDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.FileDate;
                    com.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = model.Id;
                    com.ExecuteScalar();
                    con.Close();
                    model.FileData.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Any update? Has my reply helped you?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I found you directly pass the iformfile to the `FileData`. You should read the byte array from the iformfile, then store the byte arrary into the database.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FileManager(FileDataModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string uniqueFileName = null;
            if (model.FileData != null)
            {
                DateTime FileDate = DateTime.Now;
                model.FileDate = FileDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                model.Id = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
                string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Storage");
                uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.FileData.FileName;
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                model.FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(model.FileName);
                model.FileName = model.FileData.FileName;
                if (model.FileDate != null)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        model.FileData.OpenReadStream().CopyTo(stream);
                        string connctn = @"Server=DESKTOP-LRLFA5K\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TextCloud;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connctn);
                        con.Open();
                        string commnd = "insert into AspNetFiles(FileName, FileData, FileExtension, FileDate, Id) values (@FileName, @FileData, @FileExtension, @FileDate, @Id)";
                        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(commnd, con);
                        com.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.FileName;
                        com.Parameters.Add("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = stream.ToArray();
                        com.Parameters.Add("@FileExtension", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.FileExtension;
                        com.Parameters.Add("@FileDate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = model.FileDate;
                        com.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = model.Id;
                        com.ExecuteScalar();
                        con.Close();

                        stream.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```